# html form with buttonclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

i have 3  forms with text box and button on each on an asp.net html page.
the 3 forms are to prevent validation to not happen on the elements of the other forms.
the problem is i need a 'button click' event to happen , but the form executes its one 'action' event to pass data and prevents the button click .
how can i get both prevention of validation and a button on_click event using a form???????

```
enter code here
<form class="w3-container" action="" >
<asp:TextBox ID="txtuser" runat="server"</asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET inbuilt validation controls??

Comment: ya a " required " validation its a html validation